# How to apply eslint/prettier auto-fixes in git-hook

Tags: javascript, git, eslint, githooks

I am wondering how can I apply `eslint` and `prettier` auto fixes in `git-hook` `pre-push` phase.
I tried something like this:

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/eslint index.js --fix
git add .
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

It fixes problems in my local repo but doesn't push it to the remote. Then also after I type `git status` it is written that I have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively and I have to use `git pull` to fix my problems. This generates super mess in the repo.

Do you have any idea how can I achieve this ?

Comment: to achieve this, you will need to set the hook on remote too. A common practice for team collaboration is to use `husky & lintstaged`, so that everyone who works on the same repo will have eslint and prettier running before committing. Here is an example  https://github.com/sabrinaluo/gatsby-theme-replica/blob/development/.lintstagedrc.json

Comment: @SabrinaLuo I know that I can use this but I want to use git-hooks only

Comment: You will need to either have your own git remote server or your git service support customizing git hooks. If you have your own git remote server you will need to create a `bare repo` and put your hooks on the server. When you push, you push to your own remote server, the server will run hooks for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your mess comes from the `git commit --amend` : with `--amend`, git *always* rewrites the `HEAD` commit, so your `HEAD` commit after you have run `git push` will always be different than what it was before.

One other part of the mess is that, since your hook runs `git add .` (instead of trying to selectively choose files, or chunks), it will always add everything in your worktree. No more `git add <subdir>/` or `git add -p ...` for you : you `pre-push` hook will always add *all* that's on your disk.

---

Hooks (pre-commit and pre-push) are IMHO better suited to be *read only* actions, with the ability to cancel the action if necessary.

E.g : you can have a `lint` script, with a `check` mode (check lint rules and exit with non zero code if rules are not respected) and a `update` mode (apply known fixes for the rules). Note that, depending on your linters, some rules may need some manual action anyway.

Use the `check` mode in your pre-push hook, and possibly include the `update` mode in a script that will additionally `git add` your files ; at least, you will re-gain the opportunity to *review what you have committed* before pushing.

As suggested, you can also use the `check` mode in a hook on the server side to reject commits that don't adhere to the lint rules you chose.

Comment: I know that I can run linting scripts without `--fix` flag and then if my changes will contain any errors I have to repair them at first. So In general there is no way to do that in one `pre-push` hook and the only way to achieve this is to create an additional `bare repo` as Sabrina Luo mentioned in her comment and you pointed about also in your answer yes ?

Comment: you also said that: "Hooks are intended to be read only actions, with the ability to cancel the action if necessary." But it is not true I think, because for example in `pre-commit` hook I can fix broken files and add them to this commit (they will be included in the same commit)

Comment: You can find an example with this `pre-commit` hook under this url: [use-pre-commit-hook](https://github.com/kaczor6418/fix-pre-push) at branch `use-pre-commit-hook`

Comment: You *can*, but it also means that technically, the code you reviewed when it was staged is not the same as the one you commit. There is a `filter` mechanism to edit files when they are *staged* (`git add`ed), and is used for example by `git lfs` to rewrite files.

Comment: Hmmm ok I see. So then I will go with `pre-commit` hook I think. Thank you for your answer

Comment: edited my sentence which initially was "Hooks are intended to be read only actions" ; it's obviously my opinion (YMMV), and there are hooks that are intended to be write actions ...

Comment: Which hooks are intended to be write actions ?

Comment: post-checkout, post-merge, prepare-commit-msg for example

Comment: I think that `prepare-commit-msg` will fit my needs perfectly. Thank you